# SourceTree Merge Multiple branches

Tags: branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have multiple branches created under my master : Branch 1, Branch 2, Branch 3, etc.

Each branch has his own code. But how i can merge all my branches and have a commun code ?

So far when i checkout a specific branch, i only have the code for that branch.

I'm using SourceTree

Answer (score 1):

You can Pull from the remote copy of each branch into your master branch. Make sure you are up to date and then Checkout your master branch. Choose Pull and then select your remote branch to pull from.

Comment: Let say i have some code in my Branch 1 that are not in the master yet and i have some code in my Branch 2 that are in the master. How i can merge the Branch 1 et 2 without pull from the master ? Can i just merge branch 1 and 2, work on the branches and then pull in the master after ?

Comment: Ok got it. I just need to pull Branch 2 from Branch 1 and then work on the branch 2 :)